# Database Login in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, crystal-reports

I am making a Windows Forms APplication that uses crystal report to show some data.
I have a data set with two tables and then the crystal report gets the dataset after it is populated as source and then the crysal report viewer gets the crystal report object to show the data.

But when I start my application it always prompts me for Database login : Login ID and Password. I have no idea where I could find them so I can type them(besides the fact that I don't want that prompt to show up at all).Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a comment but don't have the reputation yet...

How are you connecting your datasets to your database? 
Is it with Windows authentication? Or sql server authentication?

For the dataset datasource you might have specified to connect to your database with sqlserver authentication and did not select to save the login information.

Comment: How do I know that? When I click on Data->Show data sources it loads a tree that has the name of my data set as root and the names of the tables as children of it.I remember that when I was adding the tables to the report they were under the ADO.NET folder.

Comment: If you rightclick your dataset in the datasources window you can "Configure Dataset with Wizard". Click on the "< Previous" button to see your connectionstring. Does it require username and password?

Comment: The "<Previous" button is disabled. it only shows me the:
"Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?" choice and also : "+" sign that expands and shows a Connection string.

Comment: Okay, expand the connection string (that's what I was getting to before, my wizard opened a step ahead of you I guess, I had to click previous to get to where you are now) - do you see something like this: "User Id=MyUser; password= P@ssw0rd" in the connection string? If yes it means that your connection is trying to connect to the database with Explicit Credentials (i.e. Username and password) and if they're not saved then your application will prompt you for them before being able to connect to the db. hth.

Comment: No, there is no such a thing.This is what it shows:
Data Source=MyPCName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspProjectDB;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Maybe try this: rightclick your project in the solution explorer and go to Properties. In the property pages choose settings. You'll see a table containing your connection string. if you click on value of your connection string you'll see three dots. Click on that to see the properties of your connection string. Is it windows authentication or sqlserver authentication?

Comment: I dont have my connection string there.It is empty.

Comment: I'd say add another dataset the way you set up your first one and pay attention to how it connects to the database. Is it windows or sqlserver authentication? Can you specify whether to prompt the user for credentials? Search your project and / or google for keywords prompt, credentials, username, password. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set an external dataset as a datasource for your report? If this is the case then check this article:
http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/09/Feeding-Crystal-Reports-from-your-application.aspx